# Taking string as input character by charcter and giving output on pressing enter

Tags: c++, c

I want to write a program in C or C++ which takes a string as a input character by character and gives output when enter key is pressed. I have to take the input **character by character**.

```
    while (1)
    {
            scanf("%c",&a); //cin>>a;
            if(a=='\n')
            break;
            //do operation on the character
    }
    //give output
```

something like this but I am not able to do it.

Comment: A c++ solution will also be helpful , thank you

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you're looking for the [getchar](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm) function:

```
while (1)
{
        char c = (char)getchar();
        if(c=='\n')
        break;
        //do operation on the character
}
//give output
```

Comment: Why everybody uses break and not simply use the readed char as loop condition? `while( (c = (char)getchar()) != '\n' ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your code should work properly.
Since a scanf reads a character and stores it.
What is the error/output you are getting?

Also try comparing (a==10)
10 is the ascii value of '\n'

Comment: Why would you suggest changing the `'\n'` to a `10`?  How exactly does that help?  All it does is make the intent less clear.

Comment: Ahh... that won't change anything just wanna double check that he is using '\n' (there is no typo error) i.e. ascii 10. as i do not see any problem with the code he is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100],c;
    int i =0;
    while((c=getc(stdin)) != '\n')
    {
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is one way:

```
char ch;
while(1)
{
    if((ch=getchar())=='\n')
        break;
}// its working fine
```

And another way:

```
char ch;
while(1)
{
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if((ch=='\n'))
        break;
}
```